# get filter values

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to output some filtered results to a CSV using symfony 1.4 and doctrine.

The field i am concerned with is a date field, where there is a `from` and a `to` date range.

Is there an easy way to get filter values using SF1.4 and Doctrine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate filter forms for your models from sf CLI, they will be output in the `lib/filter/doctrine` directory. Using these forms, your task should be quite easy to achieve.

Comment: Well these filters were already there for me. I simply used `$filters = parent::getFilters()` then outputted the values using `$filters['pay_date']['from']` etc